# How to use image as alpha while sculpting?

Tags: image, transparency, sculpting

How are you?

So, I'm having this trouble while sculpting where the image I'm using does not apply as an alpha, which would change the way my brush works. It's working more like a Stencil or something and leaving the shape of the image on my sculpt.

How can I turn it into a real alpha?

Thanks.

[image: Alpha not working]

Comment: That is pretty much how the alpha works, it defines which area is under the influence of the brush. If it behaves like a stencil and you cant do a stroke with the brush it will be probably the brush settings, not the alpha image.

Comment: Right, but what settings can I change? I have no idea.

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Ok, I just found out. In the brush settings there's an option to change the image mapping. I changed it to 'Area Plane' and it worked fine. Thanks a lot!